# How to use trunk based development when using Scrum

Tags: git, scrum, continuous-integration, gitflow, continuous-delivery

In Scrum we do a 2 week sprint and ship the features after the sprint. I have heard a lot of good things about TBD, but does it conflict with Scrum? Can anyone share your workflow if it is possible for me to switch from feature branch development workflow to TBD, when our development team is using Scrum?

Comment: Your question would be a lot easier to answer if you tell us *why* you think TBD conflicts with Scrum. I have actually no idea where you see a conflict (hence I voted "needs details or clarity"). I will be happy to revoke my close vote after getting an explanation I can understand.

Comment: As I read the 2020 sprint guide there is no such thing as "after the sprint", unless you mean during the next sprint or after the team has been disbanded. The guide says "A new Sprint starts immediately after the conclusion of the previous Sprint."

Comment: think its pretty obvious where the conflict lies, "ship the features after the sprint" like everyone not in this forum does scrum it seems

Answer (score 3):

Trunk-Based Development doesn't conflict with Scrum.

Although the main idea of [Trunk-Based Development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) is straightforward, there are some nuances and variations that are situational. When the team is small, then you can commit directly to trunk. For larger teams, you can have very short-lived feature branches. You can still use release branches if you need to, or you can release from trunk itself.

Trunk-Based Development, to be successful, does have some prerequisites. A robust automated test framework is key to ensuring that trunk remains stable after every commit and allows the developers to detect errors faster. The use of feature flags and keystone interfaces allows for faster commits and shorter-lived feature branches by ensuring that the configuration seen when running is desired yet all of the code is being integrated and tested more frequently.

Without knowing what problems you are having with your feature-branch based model and without understanding the current state of the system under development, it's not possible to say if Trunk-Based Development is a good fit or what kind of effort would be needed to make Trunk-Based Development work for your team.

Answer (score 3):

The two concepts are unrelated to one another. One focuses on how you track your work and progress, the other focuses on what you use to build your deploys from. I think the underlying "issue" here is that you've tied your release cycle to that of your sprint, which is why you're relating these two otherwise separate processes.

---

The key focus for trunk-based development is that the trunk is the ledger for the work that is completed and able to go out at *any time*. The main thing to focus on here is that you never commit anything WIP to the trunk. Exceptions *could* be made for feature toggles, but the main point here is that **the trunk is ALWAYS in a releaseable state**.

More often than not, you'll find a trunk-based approach in conjunction with some kind of CI/CD which either deploys based on a trunk commit or a very tight release cycle; but the frequency of the deployment isn't inherently part of what defines something as trunk-based.

---

In relation to your scrum process, what you need to focus on with trunk-based development is that you commit work to trunk when it is **done**. Now, the question becomes: when does your process confirm that the work is done?

If your stakeholders only convene at the end of a sprint for a formal acceptance test, then that formal acceptance test is the confirmation of done, and you'll find your trunk commits will align to that date (barring delays due to minor bugs).
But that's not a given. Maybe your stakeholders are available all through the sprint, so you can reach out to them when your work is complete (e.g. only a few days into the sprint), receive confirmation at that time, and then you'd commit to trunk immediately.

There might be some work that is unrelated to the (product) stakeholders, whether it's a refactoring or a technical implementation (e.g. security protocol) which needs updating. You might have a robust test suite that already gives you meaningful confidence that you don't need the product stakeholders to manually retest that nothing has changed (because this does not make anyone happy, not the stakeholders to be asked to confirm no changes, and the dev don't want to be blocked by this either).

I cannot tell you how your particular company approaches its particular definition of done. There are many ways to skin this cat, and some of these options will be (un)available to you based on the kind of risks that your company is (un)willing to take w.r.t. balancing fast delivery and avoiding breakage of any sort. This is different for different companies, e.g. medical machines get much more scrutiny than a blog site.

So, to summarize, it's a  three step process:

- Your team takes on some work, and at some point delivers it.

  - In your case, you're working with Scrum. However you've defined your process, at some part you will consider a certain feature/task to be finished.
- When work is finished, it gets committed to the trunk. The trunk is always in a releaseable state. It was releaseable before you committed, it remains to be releaseable after you've committed (now including the new feature).
- How and when you release your product from trunk is a different question. You could release every time a commit makes it to trunk, or you could release on a multi-monthly schedule, or anything inbetween.

  - A key benefit of trunk-based here is that the effort of deploying should not meaningfully change when the release cycle is longer, because you maintain confidence in the releaseability of trunk at all times.
  - That being said, there's a general preference for releasing sooner rather than later; but this is (pedantically) unrelated to whether you're working trunk-based or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is some real missunderstanding of Scrum out there. The idea that you can only deploy into production once per sprint in Scrum is simply wrong.

Scrum deals primarily with work and task management. And has no say in how often the software is deployed. It is perfectly acceptable to deploy into production daily under scrum. It is just that the completed and deployed work will be reviewed and demonstrated at the end of the sprint.

In many cases, it is perfectly acceptable to deploy new features without them being reviewed by the stakeholders. Refactorings, performance improvements, bugfixes, etc.. can can be deployed immediatelly. In cases where you need approval of stakeholders to "release" features to public, you can use feature toggles. And even then, this approval can happen outside the standard Scrum review process.

Comment: while scrum is deliberately vague these days and you can always cut corners and adapt it to your whims, releasing before the end of the sprint goes against the core principle of the sprint loop. To quote the agile alliance : "At the end of the sprint, the work should be potentially shippable and ready to be used by a user or shown to a stakeholder."

Comment: if you don't do that you're really more kanban than scrum

Comment: @Ewan I don't know where that Agile Alliance quote come from, but it directly contradicts the Scrum Guide. See the comment I left on your answer, quoting the Scrum Guide directly.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I dont think your quote really supports that view at all. Any description of scrum has the sprint as iteration as a core principle. "The Scrum Team turns a selection of the work into an Increment of value during a Sprint", "A Sprint could be cancelled if the Sprint Goal becomes obsolete" "Each Increment is additive to all prior Increments and thoroughly verified, ensuring that all Increments work together. In order to provide value, the Increment must be usable.": Scrum, guide

Comment: @Ewan All of that is true. A Scrum Team must create _at least one_ Increment of value. There's nothing that says they can't create 2, 5, or 100. There's also nothing that says that they can't take a build and put it in a staging, UAT, or even production environment and get feedback from stakeholders outside. I honestly don't know where these ideas are coming from, but they are inconsistent with the things that Jeff Sutherland and Ken Schwaber are saying and doing today.

Comment: If you put your increment live, it's going to hard to cancel. and if you get to the demo and the stakeholders say "NO!! you misunderstood! this would be terrible!" and you have already gone live... well I think they would be annoyed to say the least. "Why the hell do we have these meetings?!?!" Obviously these days its hard to pin scrum down to specifics, that would mean lost consulting contracts. But if you take away the sprint as the core unit of delivery.. well I think it just makes a mockery of it. Scrum becomes whatever you want it to be

Comment: @Ewan That quote is horribly misguided in the sense that it's talking about a deployment process, which is not necessarily tied to the work tracking process. It is perfectly possible to do short-loop CI/CD in a Scrum environment; this just wasn't the example being thought of when that quote was coined. There are many more possible scenarios than the one you're thinking of; such as a process where devs decide what to release, hotfix procedures, devs only releasing to staging and having the prod release managed by a different set of people within the company, ... There's more nuance here.

Comment: I think this answer is getting a worse rap than it deserves. However, I would've personally slightly pulled back on the third paragraph as it appears to go a bit too far in the other direction. I say "appears" because I suspect that your phrasing is more severe than your actual intention was. Overall still a +1 because you're on the right track.

Comment: @flater thats why its called "potentially releasable", so you can hand off to some other release process.

Comment: @Ewan: You're misinterpreting what I said. I'm not focusing on others releasing the state of the application as your team left it at the end of a particular sprint, I'm focusing on another party releasing the application (trunk based) on its _current_ state, _regardless_ of what stage your team's sprint is in. To put it differently, it's perfectly possible for a company to have a product that is built by several teams, with these teams having differently scheduled sprint cycles, and still delivering a releaseable product that is not tied to any teams' particular sprint schedule.

Comment: @Ewan: This is why deployment processes are separate from work-tracking processes. They each have their own reasons for being and can be chosen separately (barring some obviously incompatible combinations, which are nonsensical edge cases for the question at hand)

Comment: Meh, technically true i guess, but in practice you do have a link to what's _available_ to deploy/feature switch which _is_ linked to the work cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think deploying changes continuously to production is often the best strategy, that's not something that Trunk Based Development requires. Another option within TBD is [Branch For Release](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/).

In the Branch for Release version of TBD, all changes go into the shared mainline branch, and from there go continuously to all developer machines as developers work, but they don't go continuously to production. When the team wants to deploy changes to production they make a new *release branch*, perhaps do some additional quality checks and minor fettling on the release branch, and then deploy that branch to production.

So for the people saying Scrum requires there to normally only one deployment per sprint, it can be done in that way for instance. Or it can be done even more simply but running the deploy directly from the trunk branch, but not automatically and only at the chosen moment in the sprint.

This may still require that featurectomies be performed first in case a feature doesn't meet the definition of done before the team wishes to create a release branch or deploy from trunk.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has the `continuous-integration` tag, yet no answer so far really addresses that key aspect.

Developers don't continuously integrate their work at the end of a sprint, they do it... well, continuously.

A TBD approach helps continuous integration immensely by recentering everything around the trunk and encouraging small, frequently pushed changes instead of long-running feature branches. In addition to faster deployability on the CD side, TBD typically results in less merge conflicts, a better shared understanding of everyone's work, faster feedback on code changes on the CI side.

So, even if you think TBD is a waste of time considering Scrum's *production* release frequency (which is debatable, see other answers), its benefits are also largely found elsewhere - it helps so much with integrating the work in *dev/test/staging*/etc. that it's still worth considering.

Answer (score -4):

Although the git branching in TBD is virtually identical to other models, the core concept of deploying each change *immediately* does have some conflicts with Scrums "sprint" methodology, where a set of features are developed and demonstrated before getting a deployment sign off.

Whether TBD causes you to change your development methodology I think really depends on how strict you are about master being the same as live at all times. If you are willing to hold off, then master is just your new develop branch.

My feeling however, is that if you want the benefits of TBD the key thing is that you deploy changes as soon as they hit master; and this will mean you can't really do sprints anymore.

TBD advocates will push the idea of feature flags here, the idea being that these allow you to divorce your physical deployment from the logical deployment. This can work but its not perfect and can have a high effort cost.

Overall I would say that there is a real conflict here between the two methodologies;

**Scrum** leans towards a more managed release process at the cost of having a set of "in progress" work at any given time which can be an impediment to emergency fixes.

**TBD** prioritizes small, continuously deployed, changes. Cutting out a whole bunch of red tape and planning at the expense of control over what's live at any given time.

Given the disagreement from various people I am adding some evidence for Scrum deliverables *normally* being delivered at the end of a sprint. Note, I'm not says you can never deploy or deliver something mid sprint. But that it is not expected that *all* individual task be delievered as they are completed.

[Scum Inc Course description for Potentially Shippable Product](https://www.scruminc.com/potentially-shippable-product.) The term "Potentially Shippable" is somewhat deprecated now, but has been used to describe the sprint deliverables for many years. The key thing here is "Potentially" The PO and Stakeholders have the right to say No.

[Aha! develops agile project management software](https://www.aha.io/roadmapping/guide/release-management/product-manager-sprint) "A product release can occur at the end of a sprint or after several sprints"

[Scrum institute on release planning](https://www.scrum-institute.org/Release_Planning.php) "One such company is Spotify. The music streaming giant emphasizes a "release train" approach to their Scrum practices, where multiple teams work together towards a common goal. **At the end of each sprint**, features are re-evaluated for inclusion in the next release"

[Agile Alliance Principle behind the agile manifesto](https://www.agilealliance.org/agile101/12-principles-behind-the-agile-manifesto/) "Deliver working software frequently, from a couple of weeks to a couple of months, with a preference to the shorter timescale."

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect. The Scrum Guide states that the "Sprint Review should never be considered a gate to releasing value". Continuous Deployment is not at odds with anything in the Scrum framework.

Comment: CD in scrum takes place on merge to master, which takes place at the end of a sprint. If you throw out the sprint as the core unit of work and you are still saying you are doing scrum, well then everything is the same as everything else and you are doing TrunkKanScumBan

Comment: There is nothing in Scrum that says anything like this. You are not limited to deployments at the end of the Sprint. Like I said, [Continuous Delivery and Continuous Deployment are consistent with Scrum](https://www.scrum.org/resources/continuous-delivery). There's a [discussion thread on the Scrum.org Forums, including a detailed post by me, explaining more](https://www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/32357/scrum-sprints-and-cicd). The Sprint is a feedback loop, not a delivery loop. It guarantees a maximum length between feedback with stakeholders. More frequent delivery and feedback is allowed.

Comment: The scrum guide states that sprints have goals, meetings at the end to present and discuss work done and can be cancelled. Of course not all work in a sprint is writing code, there's no reason not to complete something that can be completed. But if you continuously deploy _everything_ and then say "the scrum guide doesn't say we can't" well, I think you are missing the point

Comment: What does a Sprint Goal or the Sprint Review have to do with continuous deployment? I don't think you understand what the point of the Sprint Goal or Sprint Review are. The Sprint Review is not a time to get "deployment sign-off". It's an event that happens at a consistent time and a regular cadence to get the team and key stakeholders together to align. I can tell that you don't understand Scrum and this propagates incorrect information. I'm not a huge fan of Scrum, but at least I understand its intent, purposes, and the "rules of the game" and don't misrepresent the framework.

Comment: There are more things to read: [this forum post, also including a post by me](https://www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/47866/release-many-times-sprint-goal), [this blog post](https://www.scrum.org/resources/blog/increment-dead), or maybe [this forum post](https://www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/5892/code-deployment). If you don't believe me when I say that you can deploy multiple times in a Sprint, there are PSTs - people who train Scrum certification classes - that say the exact same thing. I could keep going, too, if you want even more.

Comment: Your quotes directly contradict your view : "The PO *should* therefore release at the end of every sprint". Just because its not forbidden to have an early deployment IF "..the PO are willing to support that.." doesnt mean doing it for every commit is encourages or even suggested!

Comment: At the end of a Sprint, you have something that should be releasable/deployable. Maybe it was made on day 3 and deployed. Maybe you released deployed 10 things. The _minimum expectation_ is to product _at least one deliverable Increment_ every Sprint. It could be 1, it could be 1000. It could be deployed or maybe you don't deploy at all and just demonstrate. You can build avionics software using Scrum, but you aren't deploying to production - in-service aircraft - every month.

Comment: Jeeze the second link even makes the distinction between "mini-increment" and "releasable increment". Personally I am somewhat skeptical when Scrum professionals with a vested interest in people paying them to implement scrum tell me that scum is conpatible with kanban and TBD and CD and anythign else under the sun

Comment: I'm not paid to implement Scrum and I'm telling you that you are absolutely wrong. I'm paid to help teams find and implement the best processes and methods, whether that's Scrum or something else. I've pointed to several things from the past ~5 years that support my statements. You can't link to one thing from a reputable source that supports yours.

Comment: I think you need to re-read those links. If I had to choose a single thing in the scrum guide to support my argument (ignoring the huge body of other descriptions and diagrams that litter the internet) it would be "If a Product Backlog item does not meet the Definition of Done, it cannot be released or even presented at the Sprint Review. Instead, it returns to the Product Backlog for future consideration." I don't see how you can square that with continuously deploying every small change and feature flagging them

Comment: PS im not saying you are paid, but the people on your links are.